# c++ weird behavior of constructors when using vector as the class private variable

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

First of all I am sorry for this silly question, but I am new to the world of C++ and I am used to Java and Python.

I would like to ask how are constructors supposed to work in C++. I would expect that if I assign some value or sub-object to my instance then it will not be deleted by another constructor?

Particularly my problem is following:

I have class Tree that looks like this:

```
class Tree {
   Node * const first;
   Node * last;
   std::vector<Node *> nodesVector;
   unsigned int nodes;

public:
   Tree(Node * const root) : first(root){
       nodes = 1;
       nodesVector.push_back(root);
   }
}
```

And then I have class RRTStar that looks like this:

```
class RRTStar {
   Tree * tree;
   Node * root;
   const double RADIUS;

public:
   RRTStar(const Point & point, double radius) : RADIUS(radius){
       Node n;
       n.point = point;
       unsigned int zero = 0;
       n.id = zero;
       n.cost = 0;
       n.parent = NULL;
       this->root = &n;
       Tree t = Tree(this->root);
       this->tree = &t;
   }
}
```

As you can see there is always appended one value to the vector from the Tree's constructor which is called from RRTStar constructor. When I go through debug I can see that there is really added the Node n to the vector, but unfortunately it is then somehow deleted after the RRTStar constructor finishes.

So my question is what am I doing wrong that vector or it's content of the tree instance is deleted?

Comment: In your RRTStar constructor, you instantiate a local Tree instance and assign its address to this->tree, but that instance deconstructs/disappears on closing brace.  You end up with a dangling pointer.

Comment: You are allocating `Node n;` as a local variable, it will get deleted as soon as the constructor ends.

Comment: Same goes for `Tree t`

Comment: Consider making RRTStar's `Tree tree; Node root;` instead of pointers, that would save a log of trouble.

Comment: Thank you for advices, I am currently working on fixing the code by using objects instead of pointer, but I have problem with impossible assignment of Tree and that the operator is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines look most suspect:

```
   this->root = &n;
   this->tree = &t;
```

They are taking the address of a local variable, which will be destroyed when the constructor completes.  Any use of those pointers outside of the constructor will be UB.

You need to dynamically allocate them using `new`, and make sure your destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator handle them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. It's still total mess for me the way local variables works in C++.